# Why is the button on my storyboard not being centered in a stackView?

Tags: xcode, button, layout, stack

Like many others, I'm running Xcode 10.
I have a stackView set with top, bottom, left, right, and height constraints.
I have 3 buttons in my stack and I am unable to center the button within its button box. As far as I can see in the attributes pane, I have the button centered. If I try to move the button to the left or right of the box parameters, it does not move from its left-centered position.

[image]

Comment: There's text saying Button in button - you can't see it because it's white

Comment: Gah, that was it. Vote this up!

Answer (score 0):

Even if populating a button with an image, delete the button "text" in order to center the image.